# Como puedo hacer para mostrar los números repetidos y cuantas veces se repiten esos números ingresandolos mediante teclado en un Array List?

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un codigo en Java Netbeans donde ingreso por teclado 10 números para un ArrayList pero ahora necesito complementarlo para saber cuales son los números repetidos y cuantas veces se repiten de ese Array en caso de que así sea. Aquí dejo el codigo que tengo el cual quiero complementar con lo anteriormente mencionado. He intentado con For pero algo estoy haciendo mal que no logro detectar. De antemano les agradezco mucho el apoyo.

```
int [] valores = new int [10];
    Scanner ns=new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println("Dame el número " +(i+1)+":" );
        valores[i]=ns.nextInt();
```

Comment: ¿Es Java 1.8 o superior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una solucion podria ser la siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 44, 33};

    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
        char[] charr = String.valueOf(a[i]).toCharArray();
        for (int j=0; j<charr.length; j++) {
            if(map.containsKey(charr[j])) {
                map.put(charr[j], map.get(charr[j])+1);
            } else {
                map.put(charr[j], 1);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Basicamente lo que podemos ver aqui es que primero recorremos los elementos con un for y luego lo transformamos y lo pasamos a la variable char

> for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
> char[] charr = String.valueOf(a[i]).toCharArray();

Luego utilizamos un HashMap para contar los caracteres (podemos ver la asignacion antes del ciclo for) :

> HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

Y pues comprobamos si el array ya tiene esa clave repetida (en el momento de la iteración) y si es así incrementamos +1:

> for (int j=0; j<charr.length; j++) {
> if(map.containsKey(charr[j])) {
> map.put(charr[j], map.get(charr[j])+1);

De lo contrario el valor quedará en 1:

> else {
> map.put(charr[j], 1);

Recomiendo que puedas ver más sobre esto en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: Esta solución no hace lo que pide el OP. Este quiere conocer la cantidad de veces que están repetidos los números introducidos por el usuario, no los caracteres de estos números.

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo uso de `HashMap` podemos mostrar las veces que se repiten los elementos de tu `array`

Declaramos el `HashMap`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Recorremos tu array `valores` y vamos añadiendo los elementos al map.

```
for (Integer item : valores) {

    if (countMap.containsKey(item))
        countMap.put(item, countMap.get(item) + 1);
    else
        countMap.put(item, 1);
}
```

Como el primer elemento de tu array no esta en el map, lo añadiremos junto con el valor 1, que sera la cantidad de veces que esta en el map.

Cuando se vaya añadir un elemento de tu array que ya exista en el map, cogemos la cantidad de veces que lleva hasta ahora con `countMap.get(item)` y le sumaremos uno.

**Ejemplo completo:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] valores = new int[10];
    Scanner ns = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("Dame el número " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        valores[i] = ns.nextInt();
    }

    Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Integer item : valores) {

        if (countMap.containsKey(item))
            countMap.put(item, countMap.get(item) + 1);
        else
            countMap.put(item, 1);
    }
    
    System.out.println(countMap);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Dame el número 1: 1
Dame el número 2: 2
Dame el número 3: 4
Dame el número 4: 5
Dame el número 5: 5
Dame el número 6: 6
Dame el número 7: 3
Dame el número 8: 3
Dame el número 9: 4
Dame el número 10: 7
{1=1, 2=1, 3=2, 4=2, 5=2, 6=1, 7=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás en java 1.8 puedes hacerlo con stream para agrupar y contar. El resultado lo capturas en Map<Integer,Long> cuya key es el numero y el value es numero e repeticiones.

Para este caso el arreglo se tiene que llevar a un Stream<Integer>  de la forma siguiente:

```
Arrays.stream(valores)
      .boxed()
```

Teniendo el Stream<Integer> entonces procedemos a agrupar por numero e ir contando. Se utiliza Function.identity() en lugar (t -> t) para el groupby.

```
Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
```

Este es el ejemplo:

```
int[] valores   = new  int[]{1,2,3,5,4,3,1,5,6,1,5,3};

Map<Integer,Long> cuenta =   Arrays
                             .stream(valores)
                             .boxed()
                             .collect(
                                Collectors
                                  .groupingBy(
                                        Function.identity(),
                                        Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(cuenta);
```

El  resultado es:

```
{1=3, 2=1, 3=3, 4=1, 5=3, 6=1}
```

Se requiere importar:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```